# Azure VPN Client not installing a P2S connection profile

Tags: windows, azure, vpn, administrator, azure-vpn

I'm creating a Point-To-Site VPN conection to Azure VPN Gateway, following the official Microsoft documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal. I've generated certificates and downloaded the Azure VPN Client from portal.

However, when I try to install the generated VpnClientSetupAmd64.exe file on the target machine, a new VPN connection profile is not being created. After I double-click the executable, I'm asked an admin password, then the client seems to be installing but new connection isn't added to my network connections list.

I've tried executing the setup package with "Run as Administrator" and cleaning up old connections in my \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections directory, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

OK, found a solution. The Azure VPN Client only runs on Windows accounts with *permanent* Administrator rights. Temporary elevation on profile install is not enough. I solved the problem by adding the target Windows account to Administrators group on my machine.